# Reset bounty prompt timer when OP edits the question

Tags: bug, status-declined, bounties

The timer on the prompt to accept or start a bounty should be reset after an edit of the question by the OP.

Comment: 1. It's "lorem ipsum". 2. Why would this be a useful change?

Comment: Putting "The title says it all" signals a lack of effort and/or reasoning on your part.

Comment: @waiwai933: 1. Thanks for the spelling correction. 2. I thought it was obvious - the edit may well show why an answer hasn't been accepted.

Comment: @random: Assuming that "The title says it all" always signals a lack of effort and/or reasoning on the part of the OP signals a lack of effort and/or reasoning on the part of the commentator:-)

Answer (score 8):

No, the timer is to force the bounty to eventually be awarded. If edits reset the timer, then the OP could just make an invisible edit to the question every 6 days, and keep the bounty on the question for as long as he wanted, instead of half of it being rewarded to someone after a week.

Comment: I would agree with that, but that is not the issue. The issue concerns the display of the prompt to the OP, not the bounty itself.

Comment: @Mike: Which is exactly the kind of explication you could've done in the _body of your post_, instead of assuming that everyone can divine what you mean from a single sentence.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so. Edits shouldn't change the question. Edits are to improve questions (and answers), fix spelling and grammar, etc.